# WooCommerce - building a custom api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For specific product needs, I am creating a custom api for my application to query WooCommerce.

I am able to hook into the 'parse_request' action, but it would seem that this is too early for woocommerce to be correctly setup.

I know this because if I try to query for order information, I am getting back error objects saying that taxonomie is incorrect.

What do I need to do to correctly have woocommerce initialised so that I can query for orders and products (along with their custom attributes) ?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: The answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963720/woocommerce-api-v3-custom-endpoint?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963720/woocommerce-api-v3-custom-endpoint?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do so I will attempt to cover both possibilities.

The [WooCommerce API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) can be accessed via `https://www.example.com/wc-api/v1/`.

Alternatively, WooCommerce is fully loaded by the time `plugins_loaded` is fired (aka when *all* plugins are done loading). To do something specifically when WooCommerce is loaded you can use `woocommerce_loaded`. But `parse_request` comes after `plugins_loaded` and even comes after `init` which is where WooCommerce is loading its taxonomies. Are you sure you are using the correct taxonomy names? For example, Attribute taxonomies are preceded by `pa_` so a Color attribute would have a taxonomy of `pa_color`.

If you adjust your question to clarify what you are doing I might be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I know that the REST api exists, but it does not meet my application specific needs. I have found that at `parse_request` time, all of woocommerce is NOT loaded. For example, the custom taxonomies have not been set in WordPress and therefore I need to call `WC_Post_types::register_taxonomies();`. Even then all does not work as desired.

Comment: I still hold that the taxonomies are registered on the `init` hook. You can see it in the `wc-class-post-types.php` constructor: `add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'register_taxonomies' ), 5 );` But until you share a bit more about what you are trying to do on the `parse_request` hook, I can't help you further.