# WooCommerce API v3 custom endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to make a custom endpoint in WooCoommerce API v3 in order to fetch some customers from eshop. I know that there is an endpoint available in API v3 but it does not fill the project's specifications.

I've checked this: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/ but no luck. When I use this action, the response format is in HTML and in JSON.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To create custom endpoint like `wc-api/v3/custom` you can look at my [endpoint tutorial](https://karthikbhat.net/woocommerce-api-custom-endpoint/).

The main step here is to create a custom class and return that to `woocommerce_api_classes` filter like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_classes', function( $classes ){
        $classes[] = 'WC_API_Custom';
        return $classes;
    }
);
```

After that you can use `WC_API_Custom` to return custom content.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: I guess this answer is the only register on internet of how to do a custom endpoint for WooCommerce.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you possibly write a tutorial on how to write custom endpoint with WooCommerce with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE functionality? Thanks.

Comment: author leave the latest custom way in [here](https://karthikbhat.net/woocommerce-api-custom-endpoint-v3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new endpoint base on [Wordpress API Init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/)

to your `main file` in plugin or `functions file` in theme

```php
function get_custom( $request ) {
    return array( 'custom' => 'Data' , "request"=> $request->get_params() );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wc/v3', 'custom', array(
        'methods' => 'GET', // array( 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', )
        'callback' => 'get_custom',
    ));
});
```

now simply call it with `curl`

`curl http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wc/v3/custom\?message=HelloWorld`